# How to pass File upload button content to another page and then save it in MySql DB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, file-upload

I have a page containing JavaScript named `button.php`. I use a button that behaves like a file upload button. When a user uploads a file, it redirects onto my next page `form.php` where I use another form. Here I want to pass that uploaded file using the file upload button on `button.php` After that, I use PHP code to store this data into my db. But this operation fails. Can you guys please help me find out my error? Or perhaps suggest some code which can perform the desired task?

**Here is my code**

button.php

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script>
            function setup() {
                document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
                function openDialog() {
                    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
                }
                document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
                function submitForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body onLoad="setup()">
        <form id='formid' action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/>
            <input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' hidden="" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

**form.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload Morning Briefing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <form action="action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="margin:auto; width:auto" align="center">
   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Briefing </p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input name="mydate" type="text" id="mydate" style="width:300px" readonly> </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="myfile" id="myfile" value="<?php
$filename = ""; // set var to avoid errors
    if(isset($_POST['filename'])){
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    }
?>"/>
</td></tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">

   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="12">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
$Date = isset($_REQUEST['mydate']) ? $_REQUEST['mydate'] : "";
$Date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($Date));
$title=$_POST['title'];
//$uploaddir = '../upload/';
$uploaddir = "../../../pages/upload/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);

if ($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]!="")
    {   
            //$Filepath=  "upload/" . str_replace('-','_',$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
        $Filepath=  "upload/" .($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        }
        else {
        echo "Upload failed";
        }

    }
    echo $Filepath;
////creating connection//////
$db="pacra-daily";
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , '');
if (! $con)
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db , $con) or die("Select Error: ".mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mainentry(Entrydate,  Filepath) VALUES ('$Date', '$Filepath')") or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Any error messages when the operation fails?

Comment: @MarkusBucher No there is not any error message i think my file is not passed when user redirect on `form.php`

Comment: You can't transfer filenames like this. It's a security feature. The browser don't allow access to the real filename with it's directory, so they change it to C:\fakepath\filename.
So I fear this is not working. You better upload it in one step, or upload it intermediately on your server and use the resulting reference later.

Comment: @MarkusBucher can you give me some reference code as a hint?

Comment: What do you want? A single page? You could just show / hide input fields after the user picked a file with the first button...

Comment: @MarkusBucher i want that first user upload file and then redirect on page where he can set date after that data and file save in db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84653/discussion-between-markus-bucher-and-sunny).

Comment: I found one mistake: in `file.php` in the `<input ..` you never set the value, because you don't echo anything. Should be `value="<?php echo isset($_POST['filename']) ? $_POST['filename'] : "" ?>" `

Comment: @Jeff please tell me how i can do it?